# Javascript to get elements by their attributes

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
  <span someAttribute="xyz">.....</span>
  ...
  <div>
    ...
    <span someAttribute="abc">.....</span>
    ...
    <div someAttribute="pqr">.....</div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a sample html page.. I need to select the html elements by its attributes i can get the attribute values by `getAttribute()` but i need to select all the elements first.

How in javascript to get elements which has the attribute name as "someAttribute". Once i get the elements i can get the attribute values and use my function.

Note: i want to do this without using jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

store each element in a array the loop throught each element, and if the element contains the attribute someAttribute do somgthing.

```
var arr_elms = [];
arr_elms = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var elms_len = arr_elms.length;

for (var i = 0; i < elms_len; i++) {
  if(arr_elms[i].getAttribute("someAttribute") != null){  
   alert("FOUND : " + arr_elms[i].getAttribute("someAttribute"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

In new browsers you can do:

```
var el = document.querySelector('[someAttribute="someValue"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements by tag name using `document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")` to get all the div elements inside your document. This function returns an array of elements, which you can parse and filter out elements that don't match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can traver all elements of DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

but this also returns the `html`, `head` and `body` ...

and then do a loop over all elements and look for the attributes.

Comment: i want to get elements which has the attribute name as "someAttribute".. how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

I found a snippet called `getElementsByAttribute(doc, tagArray, attribute, attributeValue)`

You can give a try to a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yx7EU/

Hope this can help.

Comment: hey `getElementsByAttributedoc, tagArray, attribute, attributeValue)` i actually neet to get the attribute value from that.. can it be done with only `getElementsByAttributedoc, tagArray, attribute)`